# How is Javascript (js) encrypted and decrypted?

Tags: javascript, encryption, encode

I am learning javascript by studying many file .js but I can't understand anything. Many of them start with:

```
(function(){var aa=encodeURIComponent,f=window,ba=setTimeout,n=Math,ea=RegExp;function fa(a,b){return a.name=b}function Pc(a,b){return a.href=b}...
```

I think this is one way to encrypt the code to protect. Am I right? If it's true, how can I do it? If I want to decrypt it, plz show me how to do.
Thanks.
p/s: I'm a newbie

Comment: these are minified javascript. you can google minified js for more information

Comment: The goal is just to have smaller files (and some minifiers can also make them marginally faster to execute).

Comment: There are few things that can obscure javascript, one is minification and other is obfuscation. In first case (minifaction) you can always use some kind of javascript formatter to get cleaner version of the JS (like http://jsbeautifier.org/ ), but with obfuscation it's harder to understand the code as it uses tricks to make the code unreadable (it still can be changed / modified and even extracted).

Comment: Paste the code in http://jsbeautifier.org/ - it will be more readable. You still have horrible short variable names and other optimizations in it that will make it hard to read though.

Comment: Paste it here: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Thank you, but I know how jsbeautifier does. It just make the code easier to read. But if I want to change my js code to make it hard to read (like what I've pasted there), how can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot really encrypt javascript. You can obfuscate which makes it harder to read and minify (which is arguebly also harder to read, but more importantly has a smaller footprint)

**MINIFY**

http://jscompress.com/ is one such minifier.

If you wish to obfuscate your code (thus making it harder to read, but not making it smaller (in fact usually you end up with *more* bytes), you could look at this:

**OBFUSCATE**

http://javascriptobfuscator.com/

**BEAUTIFY**

Like the comments here said, to 'decrypt' said piece of code, you could go to http://jsbeautifier.org/. Although when it's obfuscated it won't do you much good.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to make it become like (function(){var aa=encodeURIComponent,f=window,ba=setTimeout,n=Math,ea=RegExp;function fa(a,b){return a.name=b}function Pc(a,b){return a.href=b}

Answer (score 1):

The code you present:

```
(function(){var aa=encodeURIComponent,f=window,ba=setTimeout,n=Math,ea=RegExp;function fa(a,b){return a.name=b}function Pc(a,b){return a.href=b}...
```

Is `JavaScript` *minification*. You can use tools such as [jscompress](http://jscompress.com/) for minification

Instead of *encryption*, *obfuscation* is used for `JavaScript` which is used to protect your code making it harder to read and understand. There are tools for *obfuscation* aswell. Check out [javascriptobfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/)

Comment: Thank you. I find myself a fool when I read a code of js which is full of functions containing a, bc, Ig, c>0, a-1... :( like {var gc=function(a,b){var c=n.min(R(a,dc),100);if(!(La(P(a,Q))%100>=c)&&(c={},Ec(c)|..}

Answer (score 0):

It Means the file.js a minified version Compresd Javascript file

You will have to work hard to convert minified version to normal js files, but we have some tools see below..

**http://jsbeautifier.org/**